# how to call count operation after find with mongodb java driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using MongoDB 3.0. suppose there is a set of documents named `photos`, its structure is

```js
{"_id" : 1, photographer: "jack"}
```

with `database.getCollection("photos")`, Mongodb will return a `MongoCollection` object, on which I have the method `count()` to get the number documents returned.

However, when I make queries with specific conditions. For example find documents with id smaller than 100 :

```js
photosCollections.find(Document.parse("{_id : {$lt : 100}}"))
```

Above `find` method will always return a cursor which doesn't provide a `count()` function. So how can I know how many documents returned ? I know on command line, I can use

```js
db.photos.find({_id : {$lt : 100}}).count()
```

Of course, I can go through the iterator and count the number of documents myself. However I find it really clumsy. I am wondering does MongoDB java driver provides such functionality to count the number of documents returned by the `find()` method ? If not, what is the reason behind the decision ?

Answer (score 15):

As you said the MongoCollection has the `count()` method that will return the number of documents in the collection, but it has also a `count(Bson filter)` that will return the number of documents in the collection *according to the given options*.

So you can just use:

```
long count = photosCollections.count(Document.parse("{_id : {$lt : 100}}"))
```

or maybe clearer:

```
Document query = new Document("_id", new Document("$lt", 100));
long count = photosCollections.count(query);
```

ref: http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#count-org.bson.conversions.Bson-

Comment: Since Mongo Java Driver 3.6, [`count(Bson filter)`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#count-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) has been deprecated. You can now use [`countDocuments(Bson filter)`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#countDocuments-org.bson.conversions.Bson-)

Answer (score 6):

In MongoDB 3.4 you can only use the Iterator of FindIterable to get the count of the documents returned by a filter. e.g.

```
FindIterable findIterable = 
 mongoCollection.find(Filters.eq("EVENT_TYPE", "Sport"));
    Iterator iterator = findIterable.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(">>>>> count = " + count);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. I am using MongoCollection instead of DBCollection, as it is what it is used in MongoDG 3.2 guide. MongoCollection hasn't got count() method, so I think the only option is to use the iterator to count them.

In my case I only needed to know if any document has been returned, I am using this:

```
if(result.first() != null)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Bson bson = Filters.eq("type", "work");
List<Document> list = collection.find(bson).into(new ArrayList<>());
System.out.println(list.size());
```

into(A) (A is collection type) method iterates over all the documents and adds each to the given target. Then we can get the count of the returned documents.

Answer (score 1):

The API docs clearly state that [DBCursor Object provides a count method](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#count()):

```java
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(MONGOHOST,MONGOPORT);
DBCollection coll = client.getDB(DBNAME).getCollection(COLLECTION);

DBObject query = new Querybuilder().start()
                  .put("_id").lessThan(100).get();

DBCursor result = coll.find(query);

System.out.println("Number of pictures found: " + result.count() );
```

Comment: Yes, the count() method was provided in MongoDB 2.0, but was removed in MongoDB 3.0. I don't know what's reason......

Comment: @EnsomHodder http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/ Note the 3.0 in the URL. Tested, works.

Comment: Querybuilder does not exist

Comment: URL for 3.0 shows Count() is supported for Collection object, but not for Cursor object

Comment: @barrypicker Read again: https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#count--

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - what i was saying is your original link did not show count() on a cursor.  But, your second link does.  Thank you for the clarity.